# Chrome Your connection is not private

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, microsoft-edge

Just recently fresh installed Windows 10 on my newly bought SSD. Unfortunately, I have to installed a non-licensed and non-reserved version of the OS. When I started viewing some pages using Edge this error message prompts me **There is a problem with this website's security certificate**, but since I'm in a rush to get my terminal of configured, I just hit **Continue to this webpage (not recommended)**. To install and download KIS and apply my purchased key/

Installed Chrome (fresh standalone version). Viewing all webpages is impossible since this message always get returned, **Your connection is not private** with an error code of ***NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID***.

I've tried changing the time-zone appropriate to my location, and it still returns the same behavior both on edge and on chrome.

Any hints on how to resolve this aside from updating Windows itself? But everyone knows KMS always exists.

Comment: Start over and use a licensed version of the software.